# TSQL query to find last execution time of a UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know of ways to determine the last execution time of a stored procedure, but are there similar methods available to determine the execution time of a user defined function?

Comment: Probably not - UDFs aren't executed themselves, their code is expanded in whatever query calls them

Comment: Not unless you put some logging code in your function.

Comment: @SeanLange - UDFs can't have side effects - no updates/inserts -'cept to in-function variables

Comment: You could create an audit and as Sean said insert into audit table.

Comment: @Clay you are correct. I avoid scalar functions like the plague and haven't written one in a long time so I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Only for 1/3 (inline TVFs). Scalar UDFs and multi statement TVFs don't get inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If details are still in the cache...

```
SELECT qs.last_execution_time
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 AS X
                    FROM   sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle)
                    WHERE  ( attribute = 'objectid' 
                             AND value = OBJECT_ID('[YourDBName].[dbo].[YourFunctionName]') )
                            OR ( attribute = 'dbid' 
                                 AND value = DB_ID('YourDBName') )
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) CA
```

[image]